# Popping UIViewController with presented keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I've created UIViewController with UIScrollView in it. In UIScrollView I added some UITextFields for data input. When one of the UITextFields becomes firstResponder (keyboard appeared on the screen) and I'm trying to pop this UIViewController with a swipe gesture, I have the following effect:[image]

View of the UIViewController is getting down and I may see the part of previous UIViewController in current UIViewController. Do you have any ideas, how to solve this?

Comment: Could you please post your code for popping the viewcontroller

Comment: @Stijnk008 I pop it with a swipe gesture. To enable it a added the following line of code:
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;

Comment: @IvanSuprynovich The problem is you're seeing two animations: current view controller being popped and its content moving because of a keyboard trying to hide? That's what I've understood.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that when using custom back actions, the interactive pop gesture stops working.

To fix this you can set the interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate property to nil.

Try this:

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    /// Custom back buttons disable the interactive pop animation
    /// To enable it back we set the recognizer to `self`
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }
}
```